# OWIN GoogleAuthentication - Always show "select account form"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, katana

I have google authetication enabled:

```
    var googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = "MYID",
        ClientSecret = "MYSECRET"
    };

    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions);
```

It is working fine, but when somone is already logged into google, it doesn't shows "select account form" for him. How i can force google, to show "select account form" always?

I read about setting `prompt=select_account` but I don't know how to enable it using OWIN

Looking for help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Based on another SO answer ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23956954/2637802)), you could do the below:

```
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "",
            ClientSecret = "",
            Provider = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider()  { 
                OnApplyRedirect =  delegate(GoogleOAuth2ApplyRedirectContext context) {

                    string redirect  = context.RedirectUri;
                    redirect += "&prompt=select_account";

                    context.Response.Redirect(redirect);
                }

            }
        });
```